# Can I get content of WebView with accessibility features of android?

Tags: android, webview, accessibility

I am building a simple app that adds sound effect to other game app, and that game is running in hybrid app that contains `WebView`.

I want to get the contents of `WebView` to be aware of the context of game, but it looks impossible even with accessibility features.

I'm using **JellyBean**, so enabled `Enhanced Android Accessibility` option and ran talkback for testing, but it couldn't only read content of WebView but also crashed that game app.

I think if I could inject javascript that outputs full html source to accessibility service, it would be easy to aware context. I heard that `Enhanced Android Accessibility` option does similar work.

My question is, is it possible to get WebView contents with accessibility features?

And specifically, can I inject a simple javascript that provides source of WebView contents?

Big thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you try to call a javascript function using myWebview.loadUrl('javascript:myfunction'); ? And in your function, just display the content of the body something like $('body').getHTML()

Comment: @julesanchez Sorry for late and thanks for your response. But what i meant was accessing other application with accessibility features: that is, I cannot modify the code of target application.

Comment: It is not possible to use an AccessibilityService to access the source code of a WebView running in another application. You would need to modify the target game app.

Comment: @alanv how the default talkback accessibility service inside setting is able to fetch these information from webview of any target application? I mean how it injects the java script in target application without source code ? I've the source code but i am not getting it.

Comment: @vehumet did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access webview above api level 18. Then you should use `android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility`. After enabling accessibility service for Web you can inject javascript into webview and can get access of webview content.

Comment: hey do you know how one can inject JS into webview to access the content in any 3rd party apps like talkback does ?

Comment: Injecting JS into webview is only useful if there is content in webview we want to read. Other widget's content are accessible through accessibility Android api without inject JS. You can  also check TalkBackService source. https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/accessibilityServices/talkback/src/com/google/android/marvin/talkback/TalkBackService.java?r=798